# PHP JS File Upload result not showing

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, upload

I have a function to upload file using drag/drop and it calls php function to check file and upload it. However i want some message to be shown on successful upload, but it does not appear. Here is the code

```
            <div id="upload" class="border"> <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Drag file here</div>
            <div id="result" style="display: none;">
                <?php
                if (isset($_FILES["csv"]["name"])) {
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                    if (!file_exists("./uploads/")) { mkdir("./uploads/", 0700, true); }
                    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["csv"]["name"]);
                    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)).".".end($temp);
                    $target_dir = "./uploads/";
                    $target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;
                    $csvFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $iscsv = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
                    if (file_exists($target_file)) { $uploadOk = 0; }
                    if ($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 200000) { $uploadOk = 0; }
                    if ($csvFileType != "csv") { $uploadOk = 0; }
                    if(!in_array($_FILES['csv']['type'], $iscsv)) { $uploadOk = 0; }
                    if ($uploadOk == 1) {
                        $tmp_files = glob($target_dir."/*");
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                            echo "Uploaded";
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

and JS function to upload file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendFile(file) {
    var uri = "index.php";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            $('#result').slideDown('slow');
        }
    };
    fd.append('csv', file);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
window.onload = function() {
    var dropzone = document.getElementById("upload");
    dropzone.ondragover = dropzone.ondragenter = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    dropzone.ondrop = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var filesArray = event.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i=0; i<filesArray.length; i++) {
            sendFile(filesArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It successfuly uploads file, but does not display my message "Uploaded"

Why?

Comment: What does the network request say when you drop the file? Is it returning back a 200 response as intended? Check the network tab in the developer tools in your browser (I apologize if you already know this. Don't exactly know your skill level)

Comment: Is file size greater than `200000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `<div id="result" style="display: none;">` doesn't exist on the page when the upload happens. It's coming from your PHP script, which isn't a part of the existing DOM as far as I can tell, from this code. This means the code `$('#result').slideDown('slow')` doesn't do anything when the response is successful.

You would need to insert the `xhr.responseText` into the DOM first before that code will have any effect.

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    // first you need to insert the response into the DOM somewhere
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xhr.responseText);

    // Then you can actually use it
    $('#result').slideDown('slow');
}
```

If it is already loaded in the DOM then you need to update its contents from the XHR response (*assuming your PHP actually does respond with just the message and not this HTML you put in your example*) for the message to appear.

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    $('#result').text(xhr.responseText);
    $('#result').slideDown('slow');
}
```

Comment: This guidance helped. Thank you.